# How do I store the content of a javascript variable in a form value

Tags: javascript, html, file

I want to get the name of the file I select using the file input type and store the value in the textbox value

```
   <script src="jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>


   <script type="text/javascript">    



     var inputElement = document.getElementById('bleh');
     var theirInput = '';

    $(document).ready(function(){
        $('input[type="file"]').change(function(e){
            var fileName = e.target.files[0].name;
            theirInput = e.target.value; 

            alert('The file "' + fileName +  '" has been selected.');
        });
    });
</script>

<form>
<input type="file" >
<input type="text"  id="filename" value="">
</form>
```

its selecting the image and returning the message with the file name. but my challenge is that I want to input the value of the file fetched inside a textbox witth id="filename"

Comment: You'd start by running **all** your code after the document has loaded. When `var inputElement = document.getElementById('bleh')` runs, there are no input elements.

Comment: Oh, and `e.target` is `this`, so `this.form.filename.value = this.files[0].name`. Oh, not enough jQuery… :-(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using jquery, you'd do something like

```
$('#filename').val(fileName);
```

Without jquery, something like

```
document.getElementById('filename').value = fileName;
```

Comment: Please can u explain how to add this to my code? am i going to use $('#filename').val(fileName); in my html form or what. Please help me

Comment: Glad you figured it out @AngwaMoses, don't forget to choose the correct answer.

Answer (score 0):

```
window.querySelector("#filename").value = e.target.files[0].name
```

inside your changehandler this should do the trick. Of course you can use jQuery selector as well.

The point is that you will have to assign the name of the file to the input's value, doesn't matter how you do it.

```html
 <script src="jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>


   <script type="text/javascript">    



     var inputElement = document.getElementById('bleh');
     var theirInput = '';

    $(document).ready(function(){
        $('input[type="file"]').change(function(e){
            var fileName = e.target.files[0].name;
            theirInput = e.target.value;

            // like this
            $("#filename").val(fileName);

            alert('The file "' + fileName +  '" has been selected.');
        });
    });
</script>

<form>
<input type="file" >
<input type="text"  id="filename" value="">
</form>
```